# Is it possible to develop a Web Part without .NET

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

Is it possible to develop a Web Part without usage of .NET technologies? I'm looking for possibilities of integration of legacy (for example java) applications into SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any valid way for .Net CLR to call your code will do what you want.  However with that said, it is likely to be very low level, very obscure and very difficult to do.

A more straightforward approach to reusing your Java or whatever code was if there was some sort of public cross language interface for you to exploit in your .Net skeleton.  The obvious answer is a REST or SOAP wrapper around the Java code but it doesn't have to be that.  It could be CORBA or JMS or all sorts of things.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want to integrate Java apps, the web Part will be coded in .NET.

Comment: No problem with a .NET skeleton. I am looking for implementation details. Any reference or architectural idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this, all of which involve a .NET web part exposing external data. All of your common integration methods apply including exposing the legacy application through web services or even directly accessing the database - you could use whatever your organization is accustomed to with other integrations.

Another possible option, depending on your SharePoint version is the Business Data Catalog (2007) or Business Connectivity Services (2010). These options, while can be a little bit of a pain to set up (though third party tools are available) do allow for some automatic integration of other applications into SharePoint.